# UI Grid infinite scroll to be operated with browser's scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I am using Angular.js based framework, UI-Grid infinite scroll feature in one of my project. I want to use the infinite scroll feature to be operated by browser's scroll bar instead grid's scroll bar. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can disable browser scrollbar and set the ui-grid height to viewport height

add this css.
//main.css

body {
       overflow:hidden;
       margin:0px;
     }
.grid
    {
       height:100vh;
    }

View implementation at http://plnkr.co/edit/HXO0jQHCzfUiZzR0RiUW?p=info
```

Comment: It helped, Thanks a lot. I have one more question, Suppose a page has other components also that is above and below UI grid, then how you can align the UI grid with browser's scroll bar.

Comment: sorry for late reply.if you have components that can fit in one screen, then may be you can adjust height of the grid.